# Not able to use ViewHolder right in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

After a long time i am trying to use a recylcerview and when i am generating the onBindViewHolder methode, it is using RecyclerView.ViewHolder as a holder. but to use the holder on the Textview mFach, i need to use my ViewHolder, that i created below.

````
    private ArrayList<DatenItem> mDatenList;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.daten_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        DatenItem datenItem = mDatenList.get(position);

        holder.mFach.setText(datenItem.getmFach());    //both not possible because mfach and mDatum doesnt exist (it is red)
        holder.mDatum.setText(datenItem.getmDate());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDatenList.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private final TextView mFach;
        private final TextView mDatum;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mFach = itemView.findViewById(R.id.fachView);
            mDatum = itemView.findViewById(R.id.datumView);
        }
    }
}```

btw i deleted the unnecessary parts of the code in the code above
````

Comment: add complete class code, where you are extending mainclass.

Comment: create a different class then. it can be cleaner and give you more control over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you use incorrect generic type. You need to change your adapter declaration and corresponding functions to use your ViewHolder instead of base one:

```
class YourAdapter() : RecyclerView.Adapter<YourAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): YourAdapter.ViewHolder 
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think because 'mFach' and 'mDatum' are private you can't do that.
also you can use this sample code in onBindViewHolder :

```
   public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) 
    {
       DatenItem datenItem = mDatenList.get(position);

       holder.fill(datenItem);
    }
```

and change you'r view holder like this :

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
private final TextView mFach;
private final TextView mDatum;
public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView)
{
    super(itemView);
    mFach = itemView.findViewById(R.id.fachView);
    mDatum = itemView.findViewById(R.id.datumView);
}

public void fill(DatenItem datenItem)
{
    holder.mFach.setText(datenItem.getmFach());
    holder.mDatum.setText(datenItem.getmDate());
}}
```

Comment: I am sorry, but the other answer is right. the TextViews can be private, because they are just in a subclass, not in another class. Thanks anyway :)